# Twitter bootstrap custom.css.scss not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to follow this twitter bootstrap tutorial and have run into a small problem

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec:custom_css

It is clear that bootstrap is being imported (buttons are styled, navbar appears. But, changes that I make in custom.css.scss are not being reflected in my layout. Specifically, I have added

```
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

to try and make it so my navbar doesn't obscure the top part of my page content. This hasn't done anything though. Don't really know what code it would be best to post here for debugging purposes, but here's application.css

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

and I have included

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

at the beginning of custom.css.scss.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: When I push my app to Heroku, all works as expected. Don't know if that might provide any clues? Something wrong in development.rb?

Comment: I think it works on Heroku, because Heroku precompiles assests. Try to `rake assets:clean`. If this fails, try like this: http://railsapps.github.com/twitter-bootstrap-rails.html

Comment: see my comment below... running `rake assets:clean` didn't work for me... help!?

Comment: So i had this same issue but what i noticed is that when i first created the custom.css.scss - the file created automatically added a .txt to the extension, but i saw in the video that his file did not that the .txt extension, so i thought this might be the problem. So i thought if i just renamed the file by deleting the .txt it might work, but it didn't. So what i did was just delete the entire file, and re-create it but this time make sure that it originally did not have that .txt extension. This fixed the problem for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you, Mikhail D!

```
rake assets:clean
```

did the trick.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.  If i put the style in application.css.scss instead of custom.css.scss it does work.  any other ideas?

Comment: Try adding `config.serve_static_assets = false` to your enviroments/development.rb
If that doesn't work, and your loading bootstrap from a file called `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` try removing the line `@import "bootstrap";` from `application.css.scss` if it is included there as well.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds weird, but I did the rake assets:clean and then I just named the file test.css.scss and it worked! When I tried to rename to custom.css.scss,then it failed. I am no Ruby expert but this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on ruby version too. If you are using v.2 then try to downgrade to v.1.9. It is very easy if you are using rvm:

To install v.1.9.3 use:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

To use v.1.9.3 as default:

```
$ rvm --default use 1.9.3
```

Then

- restart your terminal
- install `bundler` gem
- run `bundle install`
- run `rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=development`
- start your server `rails s`

That's all.